# Plottin grouped charts in altair from a pandas data fra

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, altair

Here is my data frame:

| student | subject | current | previous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Math | 98 | 92 |
| A | English | 88 | 94 |
| B | Math | 68 | 71 |
| B | English | 72 | 71 |
| C | Math | 92 | 88 |
| C | English | 92 | 84 |

I would like to plot a chart like this:

[image]

How would I do this in altair charts in python?

Answer (score 1):

In the development version of Altair (installable from GitHub), you can use the new `xOffset` property to recreate the chart you want:

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'student': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'subject': ['Math', 'English', 'Math', 'English', 'Math', 'English'],
    'current': [98, 88, 68, 72, 92, 92],
    'previous': [92, 94, 71, 71, 88, 84],
}).melt(
    id_vars=['student', 'subject'],
    var_name='score_type',
    value_name='score'
)


alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('subject', title='', axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=0)),
    xOffset='score_type',
    color=alt.Color('score_type', legend=alt.Legend(orient='bottom', title='')),
    y='score',
    column=alt.Column('student', header=alt.Header(orient='bottom', title=''))
)
```

[image]

Btw, try to post you data as text instead of a screenshot and it will be quicker for someone to help out since they can copy and paste it.

Comment: installed development version of altair using isntruction from here https://altair-viz.github.io/getting_started/installation.html#development-install but still get an error: SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification altair.vegalite.v4.schema.core.FacetedEncoding, validating 'additionalProperties' Additional properties are not allowed ('xOffset' was unexpected)

Comment: @ozzboy after upgrading, you need to close all your individual notebooks that contain an Altair figure, then close jupyter lab, then reopen it. Open notebooks with figures might cause the old version of VegaLite to remain loaded even if Altair is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
df.set_index(['student','subject']).plot.bar(rot=0)
```

Comment: Thank you Beny for the answer. This for showing a chart in streamlit. I am using altair charts for rest of the visualization so looking to keep it consistent.